# Inserting one table's complete column data to a particular column in another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Inserting one table's complete column data to a particular column in another table in SQL SERVER

I have two tables i.e `AuditCalendar`, `ScheduleAudit`

- Audit Calendar has two columns `Taskid`, `TaskTypeId`
- Schedule Audit has two columns `Scheduleid`, `Taskid`

Audit Calendar looks like this

```
Taskid (Auto increment)    TaskTypeId
-------------------------------------
         1                      1
         2                      2
         3                      3
         4                      1  
         5                      1
```

But I want `Taskid` column data from Audit Calendar table based on TaskTypeId .Columns

After completion of query, the ScheduleAudit table should look like this

```
Scheuleid (AutoIncrement)     Taskid
-------------------------------------
          1                      1
          2                      1
          3                      1
```

I have to run this query seems to look like a error

> Subquery returns more than one value

Query is:

```
INSERT INTO ScheduleAudit(TaskId)
VALUES ((SELECT TaskId FROM AuditCalendar Where TaskTypeId = 1))
```

Please can you suggest how I can do this approach I am new to SQL Server but someone says that use cursors.... I am really confused last 1 week on words. And also search google but not get it now...Please can you give me any one valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

`insert ... values` is supposed to insert a single row. So what you have in the parentheses is supposed to produce a single row, or else it would fail.

There's no need to use `insert ... values`, when you can use `insert ... select`:

```
INSERT INTO ScheduleAudit(TaskId) 
SELECT TaskId FROM AuditCalendar Where TaskTypeId=1
```

...however, that would produce

```
                               1                                            1
                               2                                            4
                               3                                            5
```

I'm not sure I understand the logic behind producing your example output.

Comment: This served my purpose. Thank you.